# How can I repeat an "input" in order to get a proper answer?

Tags: python, while-loop, do-while

I'm making a little game.
This is what I've done so far

```
World = input("Where do you live?")

x = "Ideas"
y = "Real"

def name(x):
    if World == x:
      return ('correct')
    elif World == y:
      return ('game over')
    else:
      return ('insert a valid answer')

print(name(World))

while name(x) != x and y:
      print(World)
      break
```

In short, I really like to know how I can repeat the input when it is not x or y.
I really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote the code a little, but this would work:

```py
def get_world():
    x, y = "Ideas", "Real" # In Python you can assign multiple values to multiple variables on a single line
    world = None

    while not (world == x or world == y):
        if world is not None: print("Insert a valid answer.") # The first time world == None, from the second loop onwards it will contain a string value
        world = input("Where do you live?  ")

    if world == x: print("Correct")
    elif world == y: print("Game over") # In this situation, this could also be an else statement

    return world

get_world()
```

If you run this code, you get this:

```
Where do you live?  test
Insert a valid answer.
Where do you live?  Real
Game over
```

Please note that I've added a `return` statement. You could then assign the chosen world to a variable (if you want), like this:

```py
chosen_world = get_world()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
World = input("Where do you live?")

x = "Ideas"
y = "Real"

while World != x and World != y:
    print('insert a valid answer')
    World = input("Where do you live?")
if World == x:
    print('correct')
else:
    print('game over')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def start_game():
World = input("Where do you live?")
x = "Ideas"
y = "Real"
while(World != x and World != y):
    World = input("insert a valid answer:")
if World == x:
    print('correct')
elif World == y:
    print('game over')
```

`start_game()`

Frist I have tested the part to try again

```
Where do you live?test
insert a valid answer:Ideas
correct
```

After that I had tested the wrong

```
Where do you live?Real
game over
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resume = True
good = "Ideas"
bad = "Real"
while resume:
    i = input("Where do you live?")
    if i == good:
        print("correct")
        resume = False
    elif i == bad:
        print("game over")
        resume = False
    else:
        print("insert a valid answer")
print("code finished")
```